Nodemailer does not show icalendar in any email client
I have an web app based on appointment booker. User come to website select appointment and create appointment for himself.
When appointment created we send email to customer and website owner regarding the appointment date and time and some other information.
We send email using nodemailer.
Now i want to send icalendar with nodemailer. but the email get delivered but no icalendar found with email like this with email,

This is how my ical content look like,
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
    VERSION:2.0 
    PRODID:-//sebbo.net//ical-generator//EN 
    METHOD:REQUEST 
    NAME:appointment 
    X-WR-CALNAME:appointment 
    BEGIN:VEVENT 
    UID:905f99cc-4137-4700-8a4a-9fff62365620 
    SEQUENCE:0 
    DTSTAMP:20240528T075242Z 
    DTSTART:20240528T075242Z 
    DTEND:20240528T085242Z 
    SUMMARY:Example Event 
    LOCATION:SAUDI 
    DESCRIPTION:It works :) 
    ORGANIZER;CN="abc":mailto:abcd@gmail.com 
    URL;VALUE=URI:http://example.com/ 
    END:VEVENT 
    END:VCALENDAR

and this is how i send email using nodemailer
index.js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const mg = require('nodemailer-mailgun-transport');

const mailgunOptions = {
    auth: {
          api_key: functions.config().mailgun.key,
          domain: functions.config().mailgun.domain,
    }
};

const mailer = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(mailgunOptions));

let template = await loadTemplate(parentReservation);

mailer.sendMail({
       from: 'abc@company.com',
       to: 'user@gmail.com'
       cc: 'abc@company.com'
       subject: `new booking from ${companyName}`,
       html: template,
       'h:X-Mailgun-Variables': JSON.stringify({nextStep:false}),
       icalEvent: {
           method: 'request',
           content: iCalContent,
       }
}, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Mailgun Response: " + JSON.stringify(info,null,4));
    }
});

As i received the email successfully, but cannot see icalendar. I check it both on gmail client and outlook client.
Here is how i received the email.

